# Express.js - How to serve files from an arbitrary directory?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to serve an arbitrary directory (from a node.js app), but I keep getting `Cannot GET /`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("C:/test/", express.static('C:/test/'))
```

I want it to display a webpage that shows a list of files (of the specified directory) and the download link. So that when I visit the URL from local devices I would see something like:

```
C:/test/file1.png - download link
C:/test/file2.mp4  - download link
```

Is that possible?

Comment: [`serve-index`](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-index.html)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thank you mate! That works. You're awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to send a single file is to use `download` method:

```
app.get('/uniquePathHere', function (req, res) {
  res.download('C:/test/1.png', '1.png');
})
```

On a local device open the IP of the server (IPv4 address assigned by the router to the computer), for example:

```
192.168.0.105:3000/uniquePathHere
```

And it will start downloading automatically

If you want to display all the files of the directory, you can use the solution suggested in the comments:

```
app.use('/ftp', express.static('C:/test/'), serveIndex('C:/test/', {'icons': true}))
```

And then visit IP of the server, for example:

```
192.168.0.105:3000/ftp
```

### How to get server IP

```
var ip = require("ip")
console.log(ip.address())
```